# Can some cubic polynomial have two real roots?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots, cubics

In $p(x) = x^3-x^2$, both $0$ and $1$ are possible roots of the polynomial; both are real. I had read that a cubic polynomial has either all real roots or just one real root. It can't have two. What is the problem in this case?

Comment: I think the statement is that if a cubic polynomial has three **distinct** roots, then either all 3 are real or only one of them is real and the other two are complex conjugates of each other.

Comment: The title is not good. A trivial answer would be: Yes, take $f(x)=x^3$. It has $3$ real roots, $0$, $0$ and again $0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case, $0$ is a *double* root: you should count it as two roots. In other words, the following statement holds:

> If the roots are counted with their multiplicities, then every cubic polynomial in one variable with real coefficients either has exactly one real root or it has three real roots.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that complex conjugation ${\Bbb C}\rightarrow {\Bbb C}:z\mapsto \bar z$, where $\bar z = a-ib$ if $z=a+ib$, is a (ring) automorphism. It follows that if you have a polynomial (with real coefficients in your case) $f(x)$ with $f(z)=0$ for some $z\in{\Bbb C}$, then $f(\bar z) = \overline {f(z)} = \bar 0 = 0$. Thus complex roots always occur in pairs: $(z,\bar z)$.

So actually a cubic polynomial with real coefficients can only have 1 or 3 real roots, but not 2. If if would have 2 real roots and 1 complex root $z$, then $\bar z$ would also be a root and so (as argumented above) $z=\bar z$ would be real.

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you have complex coefficients instead, the statement isn’t true.

As an example, consider $f(z) = (z-1)(z+1)(z-i)$. $f$ has two real roots, but one complex root.